# Preg match all greedy with exception for string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, regex-greedy

My source string is this:

```
{categories group_id="3"}
{category_name}
{/categories}

{categories group_id="4"}
{category_name}
{/categories}
```

My regex is this:

```
preg_match('/{categories group_id="3"}(.*){\/categories}/s', $tagdata, $matches);
```

Which results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {categories group_id="3"}
    {category_name}
    {/categories}
    {categories group_id="4"}
    {category_name}
    {/categories}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
    {category_name}
    {/categories}
    {categories group_id="4"}
    {category_name}

        )
)
```

You can see that the greediness is too greedy, and it goes all the way to the end of the second instance. What I'm expecting is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {categories group_id="3"}
    {category_name}
    {/categories}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
    {category_name}

        )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.*  greedy
.*? non-greedy
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @user779

Also another way is to add a **U (PCRE_UNGREEDY)** modifier at the end of your regexp which *makes all quantifiers lazy*.

```
preg_match('/{categories group_id="3"}(.*){\/categories}/sU', $tagdata, $matches);
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php